# Special Relativity: inertia of charged particle with mass

Tags: special-relativity

In classical mechanics, we arrive at relation between Kinetic Energy ($T$) and Potential Energy ($V$) from work done in conservative field:  $ T_2 - T_1 = V_1 - V_2 $

In special relativity mechanics, for a force $F$, we arrive at energy $ E = \gamma mc^2$ which with condition $ v\ll c $, gives us the energy mass equivalence $E = mc^2$.

If we consider $F = qE$, force acting on a test charge $q$ due to electric field $E$ (which is conservative), then work done $W$,
$$W = q\int \bar E.d\bar s = q(\phi_1 - \phi_2) $$
$$\text{by length contraction},\ \phi_r = \phi/\gamma $$
 $$ \phi_r = \text{relativistic}$$
$$\text{therefore},\ E_r = q(\phi_1 - \phi_2)/\gamma = q(\Delta \phi)/\gamma   $$
Expanding binomially as done in case of mechanics, $$E_r = q(\Delta \phi) + q(\Delta \phi)v^2/2c^2$$

If the test charge has mass $m$, that would mean
$$E_r = mc^2 + mv^2/2$$

Equating above two equations for energy, and for velocity $v=0$, the result is
$$mc^2 = q(\Delta \phi)$$

Thus, can it be said, that inertia of charged particle with mass $m$ is different from inertia of non-charged particle with $m$?

In other words, the minimum potential difference required to move a charged particle with mass $m$ and charge $q$, is given by
$$\Delta \phi = mc^2/q$$
And because this inertia of charged particle with mass $m$ is less than that of a non-charged particle with mass $m$, can we say presence of charge reduces the inertia of a particle?

Or here, the interpretation and the math done is incorrect?

Comment: I don't think there is any minimum potential difference. If you put a charged particle with mass into a potential with some gradient, it will start moving. Presence of charge is probably increasing inertia (through I don't like this term), since getting charged particle to move requires also creating the accompanying magnetic field, which takes extra energy. I would advise using co-variant formalism for calculating the dynamics of charged particles in the electromagnetic fields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Relativistic_form_of_the_Lorentz_force.

Comment: Why use co-variant formalism? Because relativistic vs non-relativistic scalar potential makes no sense. Scalar potential is one component of the four-vector potential. If there are any relativistic effects that need to be taken into account, then you will have to transform the four-vector potential as a whole. You cannot pick components as you please.